# How to create a link or button which calls an action and doesn't preserve cid?

Tags: jsf-2, cdi, conversation-scope

Here is a simple usecase which I don't manage to realise : I want to create a link or button which calls a server method (action) and will redirect to a page without preserving the `cid` parameter.

I'm using JSF2, JBoss 7 and Seam 3.

Here are two methods I tried without success.

**First one, the `h:commandLink`**

```xhtml
<h:commandLink action="pages/home.xhtml"
               actionListener="#{identity.logout()}"
               value="#{bundles.layout.logout}" />
```

Here, `identity.logout()` is called, but then, the browser is redirected to `pages/home.xhtml?cid=1`, so if I login again, I will have an

```
org.jboss.weld.context.ContextNotActiveException: WELD-001303 No active contexts for scope type javax.enterprise.context.ConversationScoped
```

error.

**Second one, the `h:link`**

```xhtml
<h:link outcome="/pages/home.xhtml" value="#{bundles.layout.logout}">
    <f:ajax event="click" listener="#{identity.logout()}" />
</h:link>
```

Here, I don't have any `cid` in the generated hyperlink, but the method `identity.logout()` is not called...

Does someone have an idea ?

Answer (score 0):

Using `h:commandLink` and calling `conversation.end()` from `identity.logout()` should work. You didn't include the code for `identity.logout()`, but I suspect you're not ending the conversation. By ending the conversation, you change it from long-running to transient, at which point it should not be propagated.

Comment: The code of `identity.logout()` is [Seam's 3 security module](https://github.com/seam/security/blob/release/3.1.0.Final/impl/src/main/java/org/jboss/seam/security/IdentityImpl.java#L420). It doesn't call `conversation.end()` but `session.invalidate()`. Moreover, I've created a `PostLoggedOutEvent` observer which calls `conversation.end()`, but nothing's better : it stills redirect to `pages/home.xhtml?cid=X` where `X` is the current conversation id before logout.